# Unable to figure the permissions required by lstat

Tags: permissions, xfs, stat

I am running into this weird permission issue on Debian 10, with `lstat` call on `XFS` filesystem. I have been referring to [this link](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix03/tech/freenix03/full_papers/gruenbacher/gruenbacher_html/main.html#:%7E:text=The%20traditional%20POSIX%20file%20system,%2C%20and%20execute%20(x)) to understand how extended ACLs will work

The [man](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) page says that `execute(x)` permission is required on all the directories leading upto the path

I have the following directory hierarchy:

```
$ getfacl /dir1
# owner: root
# group: testgroup
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---

$ getfacl /dir1/dir2
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::---

$ getfacl /dir1/dir2/dir3
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::--x
```

The `testgroup` has `GID: 1005`. And a user `testuser` with `UID: 1005, GID: 100`

So, basically `testuser` **IS NOT** a part of `testgroup` And when my program runs, the effective `UID,GID` is `1005,0`. I am trying to understand `lstat` behavior

Going by the man page, `testuser` should be able to do `lstat` on `/dir1` since it has execute permission on `/` but it should not be able to `lstat` `/dir1/dir2`. **Correct ?**

I have a small C code, to mimic what the bigger program does, that executes `setuid(1005)` and then `lstat` on the path. I run this code with `root` user on `/dir1` and `/dir1/dir2`

```
$ ./lstat_setuid /dir1/
Real UID: 1005, Effective UID: 1005
Real GID: 0, Effective GID: 0
So the input File type is =>   Directory
No. of link list:12
Ownership: UID=0   GID=1005
inode no 128
...
$ ./lstat_setuid /dir1/dir2
Real UID: 1005, Effective UID: 1005
Real GID: 0, Effective GID: 0
So the input File type is =>   Directory
No. of link list:6
Ownership: UID=0   GID=0
inode no 153
...
```

**This should have failed, right ?**

If I go further down to `/dir1/dir2/dir3`, it fails as expected

```
# ./lstat_setuid /dir1/dir2/dir3
Real UID: 1005, Effective UID: 1005
Real GID: 0, Effective GID: 0
some error for lstat: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)

I forgot the `setgroups` call it seems

The user I was running `lstat` with was part of the `testgroup` so the supplementary group list still contained the group that had `execute(x)` permission on `/dir`, even after I called `setegid()`

Once I called `setgroups`, `setegid` and `seteuid` in that same order, `lstat` on `/dir1/dir2` failed as expected

```
./lstat_setuid /dir1/dir2/
Real UID: 1005, Effective UID: 1005
Real GID: 100, Effective GID: 100
some error for lstat: Permission denied
```